# Shell program to find the Factorial of a Number is NOT working

Tags: shell

I am relatively new to Shell Programming. I am trying to find the Factorial of a number passed as an Argument of my program. The script so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

number=$1

factorial=1

i=$number

while [ $i != 1 && $i != 0 ]

do
    factorial=`expr $factorial \* $i`
    i=` expr $i – 1 `

done

echo “Factorial of $number is $factorial”
```

But as I am executing the program :

```
sh fact.sh 5
```

It says:

`Fact.sh: 10: [: missing ]
“Factorial of 5 is 1”`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This won't work for large arguments.  I hope this is just a learning exercise and not something you intend to use.

Comment: Yes this for sheer learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some answers to the immediate problem.

A quick rewrite to demonstrate some bash features

```
#!/bin/bash
number=$1
declare -i factorial=1
declare -i i
for ((i=number; i != 1 && $i != 0; i--)); do
    (( factorial = factorial * i ))
done
echo “Factorial of $number is $factorial”
```

Notes

- use `((...))` for arithmetic evaluation
- don't need to use `$` to refer to variables within an arithmetic expression
- don't use fancy quotes (`”`), they have no special meaning to the shell.
- I'm using `declare` to inform the shell that these are integers
  (I don't know how much this will improve performance)
- using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop for no particular reason.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `[` in your shell scripts you are actually using the `test` command and you are not really going by its rules.

Try doing a `man test` to find out the [syntax of the test command](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html).

You have other problems in your script but overcoming these is all part of learning and I hope my little hint helps you on your path of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `while [ $i != 1 && $i != 0 ]` won't work.

Use `while [ $i != 1] && [ $i != 0 ]` instead or, if you're using BASH, `while [[ $i != 1 && $i != 0 ]]`